# How to change the scale of cbar using seaborn to plot heatmap?

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn, heatmap

I am not able to generate the heatmap as expected and am unable to adjust the color bar scale.

I am trying to generate a heatmap using Seaborn, below is the code I wrote.
I am not able to adjust the scale of the color bar.

```py
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
from matplotlib.colors import ListedColormap,BoundaryNorm

#data2 = pd.read_csv('your_data_file.csv')

rating_ranges = [1.0, 1.5, 2.0, 2.5, 3.0, 3.5, 4.0, 4.5, 5.0]
plt.figure(figsize=(14, 10))
ax = sns.heatmap(pd.crosstab(pd.cut(data2['Rating'], bins=rating_ranges), data2['Category']),cmap='GnBu',vmax=600,cbar_kws={'label': 'Number of Apps','shrink': 0.72})

ax.set_xlabel('App Category')
ax.set_ylabel('Rating Ranges')
ax.set_yticks(range(len(rating_ranges)))
ax.set_yticklabels(rating_ranges, rotation=0)
ax.invert_yaxis()
ax.set_facecolor('#4CB391')

plt.show()
```

#### current output

[image: This is what I am getting]

#### expected output

[image: This is the expected output]

Comment: Maybe `cmap='crest'` is closer to your needs?